# Are parentheses required when assigning values using comparisons?

Tags: javascript

Are parentheses required when assigning values using comparisons? Are there any cross browser problems or odd behavior when not using parentheses in these cases? Please see the following code:

```
var b1 = a == b ? a < 5 : b >= 5;

var b2 = a <= b ? a < 5 && c < 10 : a > 5 || c == 15;

return c == a ? b1 && b2 : b1 || b2;
```

Please note the numbers and vars are completely arbitrary, just wondering about whether or not the syntax is ok. Thanks!

Comment: No problems, as long as you understand the operator precedence

Comment: "Required"?  No.  "Suggested"?  Yeah.

Comment: Thanks. Why suggested? If performance is of huge priority, wouldn't less for the interpreter be faster to execute?

Comment: It's not suggested for performance.  Parenthesis have about a 0% impact on performance.  It's suggested so that when you (or more importantly the next developer) read the code, it's understood.  It's *important* that the code **make sense** before you worry about performance.  Remember, "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" --[Donald Knuth](http://joeduffyblog.com/2010/09/06/the-premature-optimization-is-evil-myth/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be no odd behavior, it may be easier to understand with parens though.